# Remove duplicates in vector of structure c++

Tags: c++, vector, structure, unique, duplicates

I have the following structure. I want to store the structure in a vector. Second i want to remove duplicate values on (`context`). What am I doing wrong?

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//Structure
struct contextElement
{
  string context;
  float x;
};

int main()
{
  vector<contextElement> v1;
  v1.push_back({"1",1.0});
  v1.push_back({"2",2.0});
  v1.push_back({"1",1.0});
  v1.push_back({"1",1.0});
  //ERROR here
  auto comp = [] ( const contextElement& lhs, const contextElement& rhs ) {return lhs.context == rhs.context;};
  //Remove elements that have the same context
  v1.erase(std::unique(v1.begin(), v1.end(),comp));
  for(size_t i = 0; i < v1.size();i++)
  {
    cout << v1[i].context <<"  ";
  }
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

**Error:**

> main.cpp|23|error: no matching function for call to
>   'std::vector::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >, std::vector::iterator,
>   main()::__lambda0&)'|

---

### possible Solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//Structure
struct contextElement
{
  string context;
  float x;
};

int main()
{
  vector<contextElement> v1;
  v1.push_back({"1",1.0});
  v1.push_back({"2",2.0});
  v1.push_back({"1",1.0});
  v1.push_back({"1",1.0});
  //sort elements@HaniGoc: unique only removes consecutive duplicates. If you want to move all //duplicates, then either sort it first, or do something more complicated. –  Mike Seymour
  auto comp = [] ( const contextElement& lhs, const contextElement& rhs ) {return lhs.context < rhs.context;};
  sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(),comp);

  auto comp1 = [] ( const contextElement& lhs, const contextElement& rhs ) {return lhs.context == rhs.context;};
  auto last = std::unique(v1.begin(), v1.end(),comp1);
  v1.erase(last, v1.end());

  for(size_t i = 0; i < v1.size();i++)
  {
    cout << v1[i].context <<"  ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique, with the same comparitor. Though why it is less than and not == is confusing to me.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams oh you are right. I thought that it was sorting

Comment: @MadScienceDreams the "==" wont help even adding just comp to Unique

Comment: Just as a warning, common solutions for this kind of problem will be problematic for data structures that lack LH and RH equality operator overloading. Basically, it complains that it can't compare `A` to `B`. I ran into this issue when using an old WinAPI stuct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vector::erase()` does not take a predicate. And your predicate to `std::unique` should check for equality.

Comment: are predicate lambda functions?

Comment: @HaniGoc: A "predicate" is any function (or function object) that performs a test and returns `bool`. In this case, it's your lambda.

Comment: not necessarily, it can be any function (or functor) that will provide the satisfy the required test (for `unique` for example, it's whether two elements are equal.) This can be done with a simple function too, it doesn't have to be lambda, it's just the latter is more convenient IMHO..

Answer (score 4):

```
auto comp = [] ( const contextElement& lhs, const contextElement& rhs ) {return lhs.context == rhs.context;};
auto pred = []( const contextElement& lhs, const contextElement& rhs ) {return lhs.context < rhs.context;}
std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(),pred);
auto last = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(),comp);
v.erase(last, v.end());
```

Comment: Oh Oh Should I sort the values? before applying unique??

Comment: @HaniGoc: `unique` only removes *consecutive* duplicates. If you want to move *all* duplicates, then either sort it first, or do something more complicated.

Comment: ah yes @MikeSeymour i have to sort them first

Comment: @MikeSeymour in the end i'll have have 2 values "1" and "2"

Comment: @HaniGoc you may also consider using `std::set` (O(nlgn)) or `std::unordered_set` (O(n), but higher overhead for small sets)

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass `comp` to `erase`; it just takes an iterator range.

```
v1.erase(std::unique(v1.begin(), v1.end(), comp), v1.end());
```

Note that this only removes *consecutive* duplicates. If you want to remove *all* duplicates, and don't mind changing the order, then sort first:

```
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
    [] ( const contextElement& lhs, const contextElement& rhs ) {
        return lhs.context < rhs.context;
    });
```