# how to remove duplicates of a vector of structures c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have the vector movements

```
 vector<posToMove> movements;
```

posToMove is a structure:

```
struct posToMove
{
    int fromX;
    int fromY;
    int toX;
    int toY;
};
```

I want to remove the duplicates that are in movements, how do I do that?

Comment: Can you sort the vector?

Comment: Write an equivalence and comparator support for your structure type, sort it, then use `v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());`

Comment: @WhozCraig what is equivalence and comparator support? like, how do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is to use :

```
movements.erase(std::unique(movements.begin(), movements.end()), movements.end());
```

But `std::unique` only removes *consecutive* duplicated elements, so you need to sort the `std::vector` first, by overloading `<` and `==` operator:

```
struct posToMove
{
    int fromX;
    int fromY;
    int toX;
    int toY;

    bool operator < (const posToMove& other) const
    {
        //declare how 2 variable of type posToMove should be compared with <
        return std::make_tuple(fromX, fromY, toX, toY) < std::make_tuple(other.fromX, other.fromY, other.toX, other.toY);
    }

    bool operator == (const posToMove& other) const
    {
        //declare how 2 variable of type posToMove should be compared with ==
        return std::make_tuple(fromX, fromY, toX, toY) == std::make_tuple(other.fromX, other.fromY, other.toX, other.toY);
    }
};
```

I declared `<` and `==` operator with `make_tuple()`, but you can replace that with your choice of comparing as well.

Code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>
struct posToMove
{
    int fromX;
    int fromY;
    int toX;
    int toY;

    bool operator < (const posToMove& other) const
    {
        //declare how 2 variable of type posToMove should be compared with <
        return std::make_tuple(fromX, fromY, toX, toY) < std::make_tuple(other.fromX, other.fromY, other.toX, other.toY);
    }

    bool operator == (const posToMove& other) const
    {
        //declare how 2 variable of type posToMove should be compared with ==
        return std::make_tuple(fromX, fromY, toX, toY) == std::make_tuple(other.fromX, other.fromY, other.toX, other.toY);
    }
};

std::vector<posToMove>movements;

int main()
{
    movements.push_back({0,1,0,0});
    movements.push_back({1,2,5,7});
    movements.push_back({3,9,9,6});
    movements.push_back({0,1,0,0});
    movements.push_back({4,1,8,0});
    movements.push_back({1,2,5,7});

    std::sort(movements.begin(), movements.end());

    std::cout << "After sort : \n";
    for (auto x : movements)
    {
        std::cout << x.fromX << " " << x.fromY << " " << x.toX << " " << x.toY << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    movements.erase(std::unique(movements.begin(), movements.end()), movements.end());

    std::cout << "After removing : \n";
    for (auto x : movements)
    {
        std::cout << x.fromX << " " << x.fromY << " " << x.toX << " " << x.toY << "\n";
    }
}
```

Result:

```
After sort :
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0
1 2 5 7
1 2 5 7
3 9 9 6
4 1 8 0

After removing :
0 1 0 0
1 2 5 7
3 9 9 6
4 1 8 0
```

Related : [Remove duplicates in vector of structure c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811491/remove-duplicates-in-vector-of-structure-c)

Documentations:

- `erase()` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2
- `std::unique` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique
- `std::sort` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort
- Overloading operators : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators